# Reflection java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I am using the following:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
        case EDIT_ADJUSTMENT:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try{
                    String adjustment = data.getStringExtra("adjustment");
                    adjustment = adjustment.replace(" ", "");
                    ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
                    String classNameToBeLoaded = "com.picpic.adjustments." + adjustment;
                    Class adjust = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    String msg = e.getMessage();
                }
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

When it gets to `Class adjust = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);` I get the following Exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.picpic.adjustments.ColorCorrect`

The package of `ColorCorrect` is `com.picpic.adjustments`

So, Why is that error being thrown? Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: If you access the class directly, does it work, e.g. `Class c = com.picpic.adjustments.ColorCorrect.class;` - are you certain that class is on the classpath?

Comment: Is it in the same apk as the activity that executes onActivityResult ?

Comment: Just a guess but it could be the wrong `ClassLoader` for your class

Comment: @DNA doing what you suggest works without error. The class that is making the call is: com.picpic.Edit

Comment: You could use getPackageName() rather than hard code it which is better practice and might show what the problem is.  You might also try com.picpic.adjustments.ColorCorrect.getClassLoader()

Comment: What about the class "namespace"? if the class is a inner subclass, maybe the ClassLoader cant find it? Only a idea^^

Comment: I would suggest that you try `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` instead of `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`.  There is a ClassLoader Hierarchy.  Each Class Loader has different class path to load from.  Since it seems the class you are trying to load is user defined one, it is invisible to the Class Loader returned by `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`(You can try googling for Java ClassLoader Hierarchy.  May be this [link](http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch21-ClassLoaders_and_J2EE.htm) is useful to you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing this is because your class in invisible to the *Class Loader* through which you are trying to load the class.

I would suggest that you try `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` instead of `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`.

Java has a ClassLoader Hierarchy.  Each Class Loader has different class path to load classes from.  Since it seems the class you are trying to load is user defined one, it may be invisible to the Class Loader returned by `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` method.  (You can try googling for Java ClassLoader Hierarchy.  May be this [link](http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch21-ClassLoaders_and_J2EE.htm) is useful if you did not know about this before.).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to fix the problem:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
        case EDIT_ADJUSTMENT:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String adjustment = data.getStringExtra("adjustment");
                adjustment = adjustment.replace(" ", "");
                try{
                    ClassLoader myClassLoader = Edit.this.getClass().getClassLoader();
                    String myPackage = Edit.this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
                    String classNameToBeLoaded = myPackage + ".adjustments." + adjustment;
                    Class adjust = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
                    Object whatInstance = adjust.newInstance();
                    adjust.getMethod("setBitmap", new Class[]{Bitmap.class}).invoke(whatInstance, new Object[]{Edit.this.stage.getImage()});
                    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)adjust.getMethod("applyFilter").invoke(whatInstance);
                    Edit.this.stage.setStageImage(bmp);
                    Edit.this.stage.showTopItems(bmp);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    String msg = e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the answer.  I am new to StackOverflow and I found that my comment were disappearing.  So, I added an answer too.